# Understanding the structure of an asp.net core endpoint route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

What is the purpose of `:long` part in the following route ?

```
[HttpGet("api/{users:long}")]   
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] long userId)
{
    ...
}
```

I've seen this on a Controller endpoint, but never used it, so what does it do ?

Comment: See [Route constraint reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference) in the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called inline route constraints; you can check an article on them here: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/inline-route-constraints-in-asp-net-core-mvc.

It makes the endpoint check that the route value is indeed a `long`, otherwise it won't select that action to run at all.

It shouldn't be used for validation IMO, Marius shows a good example where these constraints can be used:

```cs
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("messages/{messageId:int}")]
    public Message Get(int messageId)
    {
        // ...
    }

    [Route("messages/{messageId:guid}")]
    public Message Get(Guid messageId)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Depending on the type of the route value, a different action can be selected.